# UIView.animatekeyframes skips all keyframes except first

Tags: ios, swift, animation, uiview

My goal is to have my UIview notification slide up from the bottom of the controller page, and then slide down again after a few seconds.

Inside the `animateUp()` func, I use `UIView.animateKeyFrames` function to add 2 keyframes. One keyframe brings the view into visibility, and the second brings it back down to where it started. When I execute with only the first keyframe added,the view visibly moves. However, when I add the second keyframe, the view does not animate and only shows itself at the endpoint. I have made sure that the relative duration and relative start times are between 0 and 1 as the documentation mentions. I have also tried to use `uiview.animate(withduration:)` as an alternative but get the same behavior there.

Code below (skip to bottom for just the animateUp() fn:

```
import UIKit
import Alamofire
import CoreGraphics

class ToastView: UIView {

    let toastVM: ToastViewModel
    let toastController: UIViewController
  
//constraints to specify layout on controller   
    var top = NSLayoutConstraint()
    var bottom = NSLayoutConstraint()
    var width = NSLayoutConstraint()
    var height = NSLayoutConstraint()
    var trailing = NSLayoutConstraint()
    var leading = NSLayoutConstraint()
    
    private let label: UILabel = {
        let label = UILabel()
        label.textAlignment = .left
        label.font = .systemFont(ofSize: 15)
        label.textColor = UIColor.white
        label.numberOfLines = 0
        label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return label
    }()
    
    let dismissButton = UIButton()
    
    private let imageView: UIImageView = {
        let imageView = UIImageView()
        imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        imageView.clipsToBounds = true
        imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return imageView
    }()
   
    init(toastVM: ToastViewModel, toastController: UIViewController,  frame: CGRect) {
        self.toastVM = toastVM
        self.toastController = toastController
        super.init(frame: frame)
        self.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        config()
        layoutToastConstraints()
    }
    
    //layout parameters internal to widget
    func layoutToastConstraints(){
        layer.masksToBounds = true
        layer.cornerRadius = 8
       
        addSubview(label)
        addSubview(imageView)
        addSubview(dismissButton)
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            label.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.leadingAnchor, constant: 48),
            label.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.trailingAnchor, constant: -69),
            label.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 20),
            label.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 226),
            label.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.topAnchor, constant: 14),
            label.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.topAnchor, constant: -14),
            
            imageView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 7.33), //change to 7.33 later
            imageView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 10.67), //10.67
            imageView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.leadingAnchor, constant: 27),
            imageView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: label.leadingAnchor, constant: -10.33),
            imageView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.topAnchor, constant: 20.5),
            imageView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: label.topAnchor),
            imageView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.bottomAnchor, constant: -20.17),
            
            dismissButton.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.leadingAnchor, constant: 298),
            dismissButton.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.topAnchor, constant: 16),
            dismissButton.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.topAnchor, constant: -16),
            dismissButton.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 16),
            dismissButton.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 21)
        ])
    }

    //layout widget on the controller, using margins passed in. start widget on bottom of screen.
    func layoutOnController(){
        self.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        let margins = self.toastController.view.layoutMarginsGuide
        self.top = self.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: margins.bottomAnchor, constant: 0)
        self.width = self.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: margins.widthAnchor, multiplier: 0.92)
        self.height = self.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 48)
        self.leading = self.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: margins.leadingAnchor, constant: 16)
        self.trailing = self.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: margins.trailingAnchor, constant: 16)
       
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            self.top,
            self.width,
            self.height,
            self.leading,
            self.trailing
        ])
        
    }
    
    func animateUp(){
        UIView.animateKeyframes(withDuration: 1.0, delay: 0.0, options: [], animations: {
                   UIView.addKeyframe(withRelativeStartTime: 0.0, relativeDuration: 0.50, animations: {
                       self.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: 0, y: -50)
                   })
                   UIView.addKeyframe(withRelativeStartTime: 0.50, relativeDuration: 0.50, animations: {
                       self.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: 0, y: 0)
                   })
             
               }) { (completed) in
                    print("done")
               }
        
    }
```

EDIT:Based on your comment, I have now realized the issue is most likely my ViewController. I have done some refactoring and no longer use a 'ToastViewModel' (which was an unnecessary class used to hold data) Below is my controller and updated code.

```
import UIKit
class ToastViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        toastTest()
    }
   
    //the toastRenderType specifies whether the notif bar is red or green
    func  toastTest() -> () {
        let toastView = ToastView(toastRenderType: "Ok",toastController:  self, frame: .zero)
        view.addSubview(toastView)
        toastView.layoutOnController()
        toastView.animateUp()
    }
}
```

Updated View:

```
import UIKit
import Alamofire
import CoreGraphics

class ToastView: UIView {
    
    let toastSuperviewMargins: UILayoutGuide
    let toastRenderType: String
    
    var top = NSLayoutConstraint()
    var bottom = NSLayoutConstraint()
    var width = NSLayoutConstraint()
    var height = NSLayoutConstraint()
    var trailing = NSLayoutConstraint()
    var leading = NSLayoutConstraint()
    
    private let label: UILabel = {
        let label = UILabel()
        label.textAlignment = .left
        label.font = .systemFont(ofSize: 15)
        label.textColor = UIColor.white
        label.numberOfLines = 0
        label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return label
    }()
    
    private let dismissButton: UIButton = {
        let dismissButton = UIButton()
       dismissButton.addTarget(target: self, action: #selector(self.clickedToast), for: .allTouchEvents)
        dismissButton.addTarget(ToastView.self, action: #selector(clickedToast), for: .allTouchEvents)
        dismissButton.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        dismissButton.isOpaque = true
        dismissButton.setTitleColor( UIColor.white, for: .normal)
        dismissButton.titleLabel?.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 15, weight: .semibold)
        return dismissButton
    }()
    
    private let imageView: UIImageView = {
        let imageView = UIImageView()
        imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        imageView.clipsToBounds = true
        imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return imageView
    }()
   
    init(toastRenderType: String, toastController: UIViewController,  frame: CGRect) {
        self.toastSuperviewMargins = toastController.view.layoutMarginsGuide
        self.toastRenderType = toastRenderType
        super.init(frame: frame)
        configureToastType()
        layoutToastConstraints()
    }
    
    //layout parameters internal to widget
    func layoutToastConstraints(){
        self.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        layer.masksToBounds = true
        layer.cornerRadius = 8
       
        addSubview(label)
        addSubview(imageView)
        addSubview(dismissButton)
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            label.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.leadingAnchor, constant: 48),
            label.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.trailingAnchor, constant: -69),
            label.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 20),
            label.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 226),
            label.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.topAnchor, constant: 14),
            label.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.topAnchor, constant: -14),
            
            imageView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 7.33),
            imageView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 10.67),
            imageView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.leadingAnchor, constant: 27),
            imageView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: label.leadingAnchor, constant: -10.33),
            imageView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.topAnchor, constant: 20.5),
            imageView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: label.topAnchor),
            imageView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.bottomAnchor, constant: -20.17),
          
            dismissButton.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.leadingAnchor, constant: 298),
            dismissButton.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.leadingAnchor, constant: 0),
            dismissButton.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.topAnchor, constant: 16),
            dismissButton.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.topAnchor, constant: -16),
            dismissButton.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 16),
            dismissButton.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 21)
        ])
        self.layoutIfNeeded()
    }

    //layout widget on the controller,using margins passed in. start widget on bottom of screen.
    func layoutOnController(){
        self.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        
        let margins = self.toastSuperviewMargins
        self.top = self.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: margins.bottomAnchor, constant: 0)
        self.width = self.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: margins.widthAnchor, multiplier: 0.92)
        self.height = self.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 48)
        self.leading = self.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: margins.leadingAnchor, constant: 16)
        self.trailing = self.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: margins.trailingAnchor, constant: 16)
       
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            self.top,
            self.width,
            self.height,
            self.leading,
            self.trailing
        ])
    }
    //now using a longer duration 
    func animateUp(){
        UIView.animateKeyframes(withDuration: 10.0, delay: 0.0, options: .allowUserInteraction , animations: {
            UIView.addKeyframe(withRelativeStartTime: 0.0, relativeDuration: 0.1, animations: {
                self.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: 0, y: -50)
            })
            UIView.addKeyframe(withRelativeStartTime: 0.9, relativeDuration: 0.1, animations: {
                self.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: 0, y: 50)
            })
            
        }) { (completed) in
            print("done")
            self.removeFromSuperview()
           }
        
    }
   
    //configure internal text and color scheme
    func configureToastType(){
        if self.toastRenderType == "Ok" {
          self.backgroundColor = UIColor(hue: 0.4222, saturation: 0.6, brightness: 0.78, alpha: 1.0)
          label.text = "Configuration saved!"
          dismissButton.setTitle("OK", for: .normal)
          imageView.image =  UIImage(named: "icon-16-check@2x.png")
        }
        else{
          self.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0.87, green: 0.28, blue: 0.44, alpha: 1.00)
          label.text = "Critical"
          dismissButton.setTitle("Undo", for: .normal)
          imageView.image =  UIImage(named: "icon-16-close.png")
        }
    }
   
    @objc func clickedToast(){
        print("you clicked the toast button")
        self.removeFromSuperview()
//        delegate?.toastButtonClicked(sender)

    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
    
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have some very confusing constraints, and we're missing your `config()` func and `ToastViewModel` and an example view controller showing how you set things up...

But, after taking some guesses to fill in the missing pieces, your animation code works for me - although it animates the view up and then ***immediately** down.

As is obvious, `animateKeyframes` uses *relative* times. You can think of those start and duration values as ***percentages*** of the total duration.

So, if you wanted a 1-second UP animation, then pause for 8-seconds, then a 1-second DOWN animation, it would look like this:

```
    // total duration is 10-seconds
    //  1-second UP is 1/10th of total, or 0.1
    //  8-second PAUSE is 8/10ths of total, or 0.8
    //  1-second DOWN is 1/10th of total, or 0.1
    
    // so the DOWN animation should start at 9-seconds
    //  0.1 + 0.8 = 0.9

    UIView.animateKeyframes(withDuration: 10.0, delay: 0.0, options: [], animations: {
        UIView.addKeyframe(withRelativeStartTime: 0.0, relativeDuration: 0.1, animations: {
            self.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: 0, y: -50)
        })
        UIView.addKeyframe(withRelativeStartTime: 0.9, relativeDuration: 0.1, animations: {
            self.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: 0, y: 0)
        })
    }) { (completed) in
        print("done")
    }
```

Since we generally want to make code flexible, we could write it like this - ***very, very verbose*** to make things clear:

```
func animateUp(){
    
    // we want both UP and DOWN animations to take 0.3 seconds each
    let upAnimDuration: TimeInterval = 0.3
    let downAnimDuration: TimeInterval = 0.3
    
    // we want to pause 3-seconds while view is "up"
    let pauseDuration: TimeInterval = 3.0
    
    // so, total duration is up + pause + down
    let totalDuration: TimeInterval = upAnimDuration + pauseDuration + downAnimDuration
    
    // animateKeyframes uses *relative* times, so
    //  let's convert those to percentages of total
    let upPCT: TimeInterval = upAnimDuration / totalDuration
    let downPCT: TimeInterval = downAnimDuration / totalDuration
    let pausePCT: TimeInterval = pauseDuration / totalDuration
    
    // now let's calculate the start times
    let upStart: TimeInterval = 0.0
    let pauseStart: TimeInterval = upStart + upPCT
    let downStart: TimeInterval = pauseStart + pausePCT

    // let's transform the view UP by self's height + 20-points
    let yOffset: CGFloat = self.frame.height + 20.0
    
    // now we'll do the animation with those values
    UIView.animateKeyframes(withDuration: totalDuration, delay: 0.0, options: [], animations: {
        UIView.addKeyframe(withRelativeStartTime: upStart, relativeDuration: upPCT, animations: {
            self.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: 0, y: -yOffset)
        })
        UIView.addKeyframe(withRelativeStartTime: downStart, relativeDuration: downPCT, animations: {
            self.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: 0, y: 0)
        })
    }) { (completed) in
        print("done")
    }

}
```

Comment: The duration is definitely a problem, and needed to be longer. However, your comment made me realize I most likely am handling my view in the controller wrong. I updated my post with the code I have refactored.

Comment: @kelsey-debug - I’m away from my computer for a few days so I can’t check this but… looking at your updated code - calling that from `viewDidLoad()` is always problematic, as auto layout hasn’t done its work yet. Move that to didAppear or call it on a tap. You’ll likely see a big difference.

Comment: Argh! It was indeed not calling from ViewDidLoad() ... silly issue. Thank you for the perspective!